# How does \cp work?

Tags: unix, alias

I know that if you have some alias with the name `cp`, you can bypass it using `\cp`.

Is this unix syntax? Are there any other uses of this syntax?

Comment: These sorts of things depend on which shell you're using, so it'd be really useful to know that. (There isn't really any such thing as "UNIX syntax")

Comment: I am using `tcsh`.

Comment: @David: The shell syntax that the OP posted works in most shells.

Comment: @Dennis: Fair enough, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a feature of the shell and seems to be common to both the Bourne shell family (sh, ksh, bash, zsh) and the C shell family (csh, tcsh). It's based on character escaping. By escaping the first character (actually you can escape any character) it prevents alias expansion from being performed.

```
$ alias cp='echo hello'
$ cp -v from to
hello -v from to
$ c\p from to
`from' -> `to'
```

Escaping is used a ***lot***. For just a very brief introduction to a small part of the usefulness of escaping, see the Quoting section in `man bash`.